# jQuery blur() not working?

Tags: jquery, blur

Totally stumped here.
Trying something pretty easy, but it's not working:

```
$("input.input1, textarea.input1").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("input2").removeClass("input1");
});
$("input.input2, textarea.input2").blur(function(){
    $(this).addClass("input1").removeClass("input2");
});
```

Basically the blur isn't firing.
I click on the input box and the box changes.
I click away from the box and nothing happens.
Any help with this would be awesome.

Comment: any clues in firebug? what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a delegated handler as the input doesn't have class `input2` at the time the handler is applied.

```
$(document).on('focus','input.input1, textarea.input1', function() {
    $(this).addClass('input2').removeClass('input1');
});
$(document).on('blur','input.input2, textarea.input2', function() {
    $(this).addClass('input1').removeClass('input2');
});
```

There are probably better ways to do this, however.  I'd suggest using a third class to mark the inputs that need the class toggled, then just toggle the classes when the event occurs.

```
$('.needsToggle').on('focus blur', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('input1 input2');
});
```

If they always have class `input1` to start, you could use that instead of `needsToggle`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can't believe I've never run into this problem before.

Comment: This is really weird. This fixed my issue, I was earlier trying `$(".inputelem").on("blur", function() {});`. That wasn't working for me, even though the same for focus was working fine. However, when I tried this: `$(document).on("blur", ".inputelem", function() {});`, it worked fine. What is the difference between `$(document).on("blur",".inputelem", function() {});` and `$("inputelem").on("blur", function() {});`

Comment: @SexyBeast the difference is that the latter is only apply to existing elements and if the element is deleted and recreated it needs to be reapplied.The former is applied at the document level (which will always exist) but is only invoked if the target element matches the filter. The event has to bubble all the way up to the document before the event handler is filtered and applied. Note: the selector could be something other than the document, but it needs to be something that isn't replaced in the DOM.

Comment: Weirder then. My element is in the page right from the start, and never deleted. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: @SexyBeast - is it possible that the handler is being applied before the page finishes loading? It should be applied inside a document ready handler and/or at the bottom of the body.

Comment: Yes, it is handled inside `$(function() {})`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're affecting the same elements, it's somewhat easier to chain:

```
$("input.input1, textarea.input1").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("input2").removeClass("input1");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).addClass("input1").removeClass("input2");
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eQ2EZ/).

As to why your jQuery isn't working as-is, I'm unsure, I'm afraid; though I suspect it's to do with the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("input.input1, textarea.input1").bind('focus blur', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("input2").toggleClass("input1");
});
```

If it does not work, you might need to use `focusout` instead of `blur`:

```
$("input.input1, textarea.input1").bind('focus focusout', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("input2").toggleClass("input1");
});
```

Comment: the `focusout` event does it for me, combined with `blur` to be absolutely sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Also if your elements loaded with ajax use $(document).on(event,selector,function) , because standart eg. $(selector).click(function() ...  will not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you are on jQuery < 1.7.

And [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are on 1.7 or greater.

Don't use `.live()` since it is waaaaay slower.